# Windows Federated Search and non-HTTP URLs in results. Results blocked by Internet security settings

Tags: windows, security, internet-explorer

I built a web service and connected it to Windows Federated Search successfully.

Windows Search displays the results just fine when the URL returned by the web service for each result has an URI scheme of http or https but the results are blocked otherwise.

For example, URLs like "file:///C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample%20Pictures/Chrysanthemum.jpg", "mailto:someone@example.com", "onenote://note/", etc., all fail. I am particularly interested in opening items with custom URI schemes.

[Internet security settings blocking search results with file scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVQch.png)

[Internet security settings blocking search results with mailto scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAOjd.png)

I spent several hours reading about Protected Mode, doing changes to the security zones, changing "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\ProtocolDefaults", "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Low Rights\ElevationPolicy", "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute", running explorer.exe elevated (to check the integrity level was the problem) and even disabling Protected Mode and UAC but the result is the same so I wonder if this way of extending Windows Search was designed to support non-HTTP schemes.

I am using Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 64-bit and Internet Explorer 11.

Answer (score 0):

> "I wonder if this way of extending Windows Search was designed to
>   support non-HTTP schemes."

My guess is "No" it wasn't, and that the lockdown there is present for security reasons. You could probably return a HTTPS URL to a web server that itself redirects to the target protocol or attempts to invoke it.